# In Python how can I replace a value in a text file with a new updated version of that value using a function?

Tags: python, function, document

I've programmed a game in which you get the current score for the player (score) and then there is the highest achieved score (high_score) that gets saved in a .txt document, I need to be able to compare these values and if the score > high_score I need to be able to update it and I can't figure out how to, any help is appreciated.

```
file = open('save.txt','r+')
saved = file.read()
file.close()

high_score = saved
high_score = int(high_score)
global score
score = 21

def checkscore():
    if score > high_score:
        file = open('save.txt' , 'w+')
        file.write(file.read().replace(saved,str(score)))
        file.close()
    else:
        file.close()
    return

checkscore()
```

This is what i've tried so far, just seems to delete whats in the document.

Comment: Have you tried anything? (In the direction of your goal)

Comment: Indentation matters in Python; it's unreadable in comments. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ChrisWilliams You are not closing the file .. Use `file.close()`

Comment: There is only one file object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a function to replace the score when needed. Something like:

```
def update_score(new_score, file_name="save.txt"):
    with open(file_name,'r+') as saved_file:
        existing_score = int(saved_file.read())
    if new_score > existing_score:
        # replace existing score
        with open(file_name,'w') as saved_file:
            saved_file.write(str(new_score))
```

**Edit:** It uses a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) (with ... as ...). You can also [read here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/).

Comment: Noob question but what does the as actually do?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams see edit. In short: makes sure the file is closed when it's no longer needed.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams if this answers your question you can accept it as the answer using the check mark next to it.